# iOS - Add a UIView to a specific segment in a UISegmentedControl?(using Interface Builder?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, uisegmentedcontrol, custom-view

I want to add some badge functionality to a certain segment in my `UISegmentedControl` and add some constraints but looking in `Xcode` there doesn't seem to be anyway to work with individual segments within the `UISegmentedControl` in `Interface Builder`. Am I missing something or is this not possible (and you have to set all that up in code?)

Also if it isn't possible to have access to the individual segments in `IB` then that needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : https://github.com/dave-thompson/MESegmentedControl.

This is a subclass of **SegmentedControl** which will allow easily add badges to segment control.